# If it's the first day of the quarter execute insert statement, if not, nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, if-statement, date-arithmetic

I am trying to write the code to execute an insert statement in perpetuity. I want to execute the insert statement on the first day of every quarter. The statement will run every day. It should ask, is today the first day of the quarter? If no, nothing happens. If yes, the insert statement will run.

I've played around using the `QUARTER()` function, but just can't seem to get anything going.

Comment: Why have it run every day check if it's the first day of a quarter? Agent can *easily* run a task on the [first day of every 3rd month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5FAp.png) (for example).

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: as commented by @Thom A, it would probably be simpler to plan the task to run on the first day of each quarter rather than execute it every day and then ignore non-quarter starts.

As for your question: you can use date functions to check whether today is the first day of a quarter, eg with a predicate like:

```sql
day(getdate()) = 1                    -- first day of the month...
and month(getdate()) in (1, 4, 7, 10) -- in month 1 (january), 4 (april), 7 (july), 10 (october)
```

We could also phrase it like:

```sql
day(getdate()) = 1
and month(getdate()) % 3 = 1
```

And you can put the predicate in your `insert` query like:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3)
select v.*
from ( values ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') )
where day(getdate()) = 1 and month(getdate()) % 3 = 1
```